# Applying an event handler to elements through a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to add an Event Handler for all of my `<td>` tags. I've tried the following:

```
var allSquares = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0, len = allSquares.length; i < len; i++){
allSquares[i].addEventListener('ondragover', allowDrop, false);

}
```

Anyone has an idea why it didn't work?
Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally event names passed to `addEventListener` do not start with `"on"`.

```
allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the W3-method `addEventListener` you don't put an `"on"` before the event's name (like you do for Microsoft):

```
allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop, false);
```

See Quirksmode's [article on the two advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).